# How to access offline files in iOS (React Native)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In my application, I am using a WebView to display HTML content to the users. Currently, for the Android platform, I am loading the content using the following path: `file:///android_asset/assets`. This path is specific to Android and works well on that system.

However, the challenge arises when I need to make this functionality available to iOS users as well. The iOS platform uses a different approach to load local files, and the path I am using currently  obviously won't work on iOS.

My question is: how can I adapt this process to make it compatible for both Android and iOS? How can I load the same HTML content in a WebView, but this time do it correctly for iOS devices?
Another approach I tried was to place all the JavaScript in a single HTML file, but it's unfeasible since I'm using a "core" file that contains all the minified JavaScript, meaning it has over 40 thousand lines of code. Is there any other way out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow... First step should always be searching. Quick search (using google) for `react native ios local javascript files` returns lots of matches. I expect you'll find the info you need pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you, DonMag! I've searched but haven't found any solution. Anyway, I will keep trying to solve this problem. Regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const indexHTML = Platform.select({
  ios: RNFS.MainBundlePath + '/Web.bundle/index.html',
  android: 'file:///android_asset/index.html',
}) as string;


<WebView
  source={{uri: indexHTML}}
 />
```